# using scanf("%d ") with a space after the %d

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

In my c class today I was troubling with the scanf() command, we were just learning pointers and we got a question asking us to get an array, and print it reversed without using the [] for anything but declaring the (int) array. Of course it seems like a piece of cake but not when you accidentally write:

> scanf("%d ", arr + i);

Did you notice the space after the %d? Sure did take me a while to figure it out but for some reason that makes loops go crazy, and I wanted you guys to help me (and my teachers) to figure out why does that happen. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 10
void arrayInput(int * arr, unsigned int len);
void arrayReverseOutput(int * arr, unsigned int len);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[LEN] = { 0 };
    arrayInput(arr, LEN);
    arrayReverseOutput(arr, LEN);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void arrayInput(int * arr, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        //printf("i = %d \n", i); see what happens when you use this line
        scanf("%d ", arr + i);
    }
}

void arrayReverseOutput(int * arr, unsigned int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("The numbers in reverse order: ");
    for (i = --len; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
}
```

I'm really curios to see what's going on with that scanf... it's as if it requires 2 inputs at the first time it runs but somehow still manages to put the inputs in their right position in the array...
Thanks for taking your time to read this <3

Comment: Did you and your teachers read the documentation of `scanf`? Apply the behaviour to the input? Why not check the result of `scanf`? Use a debugger? What **specifically** was unclear?

Comment: A space after `%d` must be matched. A space before `%d` is unnecessary.

Comment: Well, what's unclear is - how come the code requires to insert another input? how does it know which part of the array does it go to? because what I understood was that:
i = 0: gets the first and second numbers
i = 1: gets the third number
...
i = 9: gets the 11th number, which isn't printed
@Olaf

Comment: How come a space afer %d must be matched? why does that happen? @WeatherVane

Comment: Because that is the way the function is implemented. Did you yet read the man page? It will take you well over the 25 minutes since you posted the question, to absorb the detail of this complex set of functions, and to understand why you must always check the function's returned value: the number of items successfully scanned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A whitespace character in the format string tells `scanf()` to match zero or more whitespace characters, until the match fails. Spaces (`' '`), newlines(`'\n'`), carriage returns (`'\r'`), and tabs (`'\t'`) are among the whitespace characters. When a space occurs at the end of a format string, `scanf()` will try to match whitespace characters from the input until no match is found. But, `scanf()` can only return when a match fails, or end of file is reached. Thus, in the case of a statement like:

```
scanf("%d ", arr + i);
```

the call to `scanf()` will appear to hang, greedily waiting for more input from the user. Whenever the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, a newline is sent and matched by `scanf()`, which is still waiting for a failing match. Or end of file. You can escape such a loop by signalling end of file from the keyboard with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on Linux, or <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> on Windows.

It is almost always a mistake to terminate a `scanf()` format string with a space. A newline (`'\n'`) is also a whitespace character, and has the same effect when placed at the end of a format string.

Note that spaces can be used effectively in `scanf()` format strings. For example:

```
int retval = scanf(" %c %c", &c1, &c2);
```

Here, if a previous IO operation has left a newline in the input stream (a not uncommon occurrence), the leading whitespace directs `scanf()` to read and ignore it. The second space in the format string tells `scanf()` to expect zero or more whitespace characters between the input characters to be converted. This allows the user to input the characters with an intervening space. Without the added whitespace, if a user entered `a b\n`, `c2` would end up holding the value for a space character, and the `b` would be left behind in the input stream for the next IO operation to pick up. Also note that `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions, allowing the program to check whether the input is as expected. If `retval` in the above line is anything other than `2`, something has gone wrong.