# error with scanf and array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm trying to take integers from the user ,store them in array then do some math with them 
but the array is take 5 elements instead of 4

I can't see what I did wrong so can someone point to me where I did go wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
int NumMsg[4];
int i =0;

printf("enter the msg one muber at the time and press enter: ");
for (i=0;i<4;i++){

    scanf("%d\n",&NumMsg[i]);                        
}
printf("the number before dycrption is :\n");
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%d",NumMsg[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the `\n` from the end of `scanf` format. Also check the *return value of `scanf`*

Comment: Remove `\n` from `scanf("%d\n",&NumMsg[i]);`. It should fix the issue.

Comment: Also `\n` doesn't mean "expect `\n`" - it means: "eat all following whitespace charaters until a non-whitespace character or `EOF` follows.

Comment: it worked 
thank you but can you explain the resone between the \n and the error

Comment: The `\n` in the scanf has no bearing on why only 4 values are read in ... the problem is the `i<4` in the for loop which should be `i<5`

Comment: @ChrisTurner -- `int NumMsg[4];`, so only 4 values _should_ be read. OP states that "the array is take 5 elements," but I think that this means that the user must enter 5 elements, not that 5 elements are stored in the array. This is a consequence of the trailing whitespace character, which causes `scanf()` to wait for further input after **Enter** is pressed.

Comment: @DavidBowling ah - confusingly worded question made it look like they were getting 4, but wanted 5.

Comment: @m.lotfyzidan -- [Here is an answer I wrote that discusses trailing whitespace characters in `scanf()` format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033218/6879826)