# C scanf skipping second time

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I have read about placing whitespace in front of scanf but I everything I try does not work. I am trying to read in two sets of three integers. The first scanf works fine while the second does not. I am frustrated because I try everything that I see in forums with placing spaces in front or newline characters and nothing works.

Code in question:

```
// Get user input for the two dates:
printf("Enter Date #1 in format mm:dd:yyyy \n");
scanf("%i:%i:%i\n", &D1.month, &D1.day, &D1.year);

printf("Enter Date #2 in format mm:dd:yyyy\n");
scanf("%i:%i:%i", &D2.month, &D2.day, &D2.year);
```

I tried to put a space AND a newline character in there separatly and together, I tried to read in a dummy variable character to see if that would work. Why can I not enter any data in the second scanf??

The output is shown:

```
Enter Date #1 in format mm:dd:yyyy 
09:06:1995
Enter Date #2 in format mm:dd:yyyy
The number of days between 0:1529117256:94769206 and 9:6:1995 is -1783102426
```

I make a new post because I see explanations with characters but not with integers.

Comment: Note that using whitespace characters (such as `\n`) at the end of a `scanf()` format string [causes havoc with interactive input.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033218/6879826)

Comment: Why did you specify that `\n` at the end of the first `scanf` format? What did you try to achieve?

Comment: Tip: whenever `scanf()` does not act as expected,test the return value from `scanf()` to gain insight.  `int cnt = scanf("%i:%i:%i\n", &D1.month, &D1.day, &D1.year); if (cnt  != 3) printf("Something amiss %d\n", cnt);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `%i` with `scanf`:

```
scanf("%i",&inp);  //INPUT 09 AS MONTH OR ANYTHING
```

It will read input as **octal** due the prefixed `0` or leading zero when input is `09`, hence the value of `inp` becomes invalid since `9` is not a valid octal digit, octal digits being `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`.

Where as in case when `%d` is being used than `09` input will not be converted into **octal** and the value read will be `9`.

Apart from this there is something I would like to suggest: [away-from-scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 2):

As given in comment (1) by user3121023 changin both to "%d" 's instead of "%i" 's fixed the issue. I am unclear why.

Code is now:

```
// Get user input for the two dates:
printf("Enter Date #1 in format mm:dd:yyyy \n");
scanf("%d:%d:%d", &D1.month, &D1.day, &D1.year);

printf("Enter Date #2 in format mm:dd:yyyy\n");
scanf("%d:%d:%d", &D2.month, &D2.day, &D2.year);
```

Comment: "I am unclear why.' (removing `'\n'`) --> Answering the question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582254/c-scanf-skipping-second-time#comment92100281_52582254) is the first step.  The answer is in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582254/c-scanf-skipping-second-time#comment92100138_52582254)

Answer (score 2):

In addition:

```
"%d:%d:%d\n"
```

would not work. Do not put '\n' in your scanf.