# error: conflicting types, error: type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete

Tags: c, function, structure

> I'm writing a code that calculates the difference in days between 2 given dates. Note that each month is considered to be equal to 30 days and each year equal to 360 days.
>
> I'm getting the following warning/errors and I don't seem to understand why:

[Warning&Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ite.png)

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dif_days(struct Date Date1, struct Date Date2);

struct Date
{
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
};

int main()
{
    struct Date Date1;
    struct Date Date2;

    printf("\n Please enter the first date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &Date1.Day, &Date1.Month, &Date1.Year);

    printf("\n Please enter the second date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &Date2.Day, &Date2.Month, &Date2.Year);

    int diff = dif_days(Date1, Date2);
    printf("\n The difference in days is: %d \n", diff);

    return 0;
}

int dif_days(struct Date Date1, struct Date Date2)
{
    // variable declaration 
    int difference;
    int Day, Month, Year; // The final days/months/years

    // for the days
    if (Date1.Day > Date2.Day)
        Day = Date1.Day - Date2.Day;
    else    
        Day = Date2.Day - Date1.Day;

    // for the months
    if (Date1.Month > Date2.Month) 
        Month = Date1.Month - Date2.Month;
    else
        Month = Date2.Month - Date1.Month;

    // for the years
    if (Date1.Year > Date2.Year)
        Year = Date1.Year - Date2.Year;
    else        
        Year = Date2.Year - Date1.Year;       

    difference = Day + Month*30 + Year*360;                

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Your prototype definition `int dif_days(struct Date Date1, struct Date Date2);` uses struct Data which is not defined at this time. So move it after the definition of `struct Date`. Besides this, your calculation is wrong is so many ways; did you test with "16 12 2018" and  "16 12 2018"? "31 12 2018" and "1 1 2019"?

Comment: @KlausGütter I've already moved the struct Date over the prototype definition. I tried testing "16 12 2018" and "16 12 2018" and I got zero. However, the other combination that you recommended me did not seem to give a valid answer so I will have a look at my algorithm again. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @KlausGütter I managed to re-write the code and it now works like a charm but there's still a little problem. If the user enters "31 12 2018" and "1 1 2019" the answer is 0. Should I add an if statement at my function that will check whether or not the user has entered more than 30 days so that they can be converted to 30 since that is the maximum value that the variable `day` can have.

Comment: Why not just calculate `360*year + 30*month + day` for both days and take the difference?

Comment: @KlausGütter that's what I did. I calculated the days of each date separately and then I made an `if` statement like this: `if (days_of_date1 > days_of_date2) difference = days_of_date1 - days_of_date2; else difference = days_of_date2 - days_of_date1;`

Comment: Because your months have only 30 days, it is clear that the 31th of December is in fact the 1st of Jauary ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `struct Date` before you use it in the function prototype for `dif_days()`.

You can either move the entire definition of the `struct` so that it comes before the function prototype, or you can use a forward declaration for the `struct` by adding before the function prototype:

```
struct Date;
```

Also, you need to remove the trailing whitespace characters from your `scanf()` format strings. [This plays havoc with interactive input, and does not do what people usually seem to expect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032984/using-scanfd-with-a-space-after-the-d) Note that the `%d` directive automatically ignores leading whitespace characters, and in fact the only `scanf()` directives that *do not* ignore leading whitespaces are `%c`, `%n`, and `%[]`.

And while we're on the topic of `scanf()`, you should be checking the value returned by calls to `scanf()` to ensure that input is as expected. Once a match fails in the format string, `scanf()` will move on without storing anything in the remaining variables. Invalid inputs will lead to undefined behavior when the code attempts to use indeterminate values. Here `scanf()` will return 3 if three numbers are entered, and for basic validation you could check that the user did in fact enter three numbers before continuing.

Comment: Your answer seems to resolve the warning and the errors. However, I have one more question to ask, if you don't mind answering. Could I also use &i instead of &d? If so, would that change cause any unwanted behavior to the overall performance of the program?

Comment: The `%i` directive allows input in C integer constant formats, allowing hex or octal literals to be input. This is likely to lead to confusion unless this special behavior is what you want. I would stick with `%d` to avoid surprises, and because the behavior you probably want is to expect only decimal inputs. In particular, an octal literal like `010` could be input with `%i` and the value stored would be 8, which may come as a surprise.