# problem creating a code to print maximum between 3 numbers

Tags: c, if-statement, numbers, max, codeblocks

I wrote a  program which takes three numbers from the user and prints out the maximum number, but when I run the program it is not taking the numbers from the user correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    printf ("PROGRAM TO FIND THE BIGGEST NUMBER\n");
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("enter first number : ");
    scanf ("%d ",&num1);

    printf ("enter second number : ");
    scanf ("%d ",&num2);

    printf ("enter third number : ");
    scanf ("%d ",&num3);

    printf("%d - %d - %d \n",num1,num2,num3);


    if (num1>num2 && num1>num3){
        printf ("the biggest number is %d",num1);
    }
    else if  (num2>num1 && num2>num3){
        printf ("the biggest number is %d",num2);
    }
    else if (num3>num1 && num3>num2){
        printf ("the biggest number is %d",num3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not taking the numbers from the user correctly"?

Comment: remove space after %d in scanf because by doing so you're ignoring all white spaces

Comment: @Abhinav Gangwar I can not reproduce. Nevertheless the program logically is incorrect.

Comment: In particular, your program would print nothing for the inputs "5, 3, 5".

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the %d in all the scanf calls.  The space will match any character including the newline.  The scanf will keep reading until the match fails.  By removing the space the match fails when the newline character is entered and the code continues.

Comment: And how does the space influence on the input of integers?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - Here are some details: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033218/7218062