# Why does my code shows blank space after running?

Tags: c

I am beginner in C and started self learning it.
My code here basically attempts to calculate the weekly wage of a worker
I have to input no. of hours per week from the user.
This is the problem I'm working on

> In this challenge you are to create a C program that calculates you
>   weekly pay.
>
> The program should ask the user to end the number of hours worked in a
>   week via the keyboard
>
> The program should display as output the gross pay, the taxes, and the
>   net pay.
>
> The following assumptions should be made:
>
> - Basic pay rate = $12.00/hr
> - Overtime (in excess of 40 hours) = time and a half
> - Tax rate:
>
>   - 15% of the first $300
>   - 20% of the next $150
>   - 25% of the rest

As I run the code it asks me to input no. of hours which after entering displays nothing but blank space
I know its very long and simple but still I am facing problems

Help very much appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float hrs=0;
    float grossPay,taxes,netPay;
    float bpr=12.00;
    printf("The number of hours worked in a week: ");
    scanf("%f\n",&hrs);
    if (hrs<=40)
        grossPay=(hrs*bpr);
        printf("Gross Pay:%f\n",grossPay);
        if (grossPay<=300)
            taxes=0.15*grossPay;
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        if (grossPay>300 && grossPay<=450)
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*(grossPay-300);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        if (grossPay>450)
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*150+0.25*(grossPay-450);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
    if (hrs>40)
        grossPay=40*bpr+18.00*(hrs-40);
        printf("Gross Pay:%f\n",grossPay);
        if (grossPay<=300)
            taxes=0.15*grossPay;
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        if (grossPay>300 && grossPay<=450)
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*(grossPay-300);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        if (grossPay>450)
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*150+0.25*(grossPay-450);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);


   return 0;
}
```

I made a alternative code for the same.Which is more efficient?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAYRATE 12.00
#define TAXRATE_300 .15
#define TAXRATE_150 .20
#define TAXRATE_REST .25
#define OVERTIME 40

int main()
{

   int hrs = 0;
   double grossPay = 0.0;
   double taxes = 0.0;
   double netPay = 0.0;

   printf("The number of hrs worked this week: ");

   scanf("%d", &hrs);


   if (hrs <= 40)
       grossPay = hrs * PAYRATE;
   else
   {
     grossPay = 40 * PAYRATE;
     double overTimePay = (hrs - 40) * (PAYRATE * 1.5);
     grossPay += overTimePay;
   }


   if (grossPay <= 300)
   {
       taxes = grossPay * TAXRATE_300;
   }
   else if(grossPay > 300 && grossPay <= 450)
   {
       taxes = 300 * TAXRATE_300;
       taxes += (grossPay - 300) * TAXRATE_150;
   }
   else if (grossPay > 450)
   {
       taxes = 300 * TAXRATE_300;
       taxes += 150 * TAXRATE_150;
       taxes += (grossPay - 450) * TAXRATE_REST;
   }


   netPay = grossPay - taxes;


   printf("Your gross pay this week is: %.2f\n", grossPay);
   printf("Your taxes this week is: %.2f\n", taxes);
   printf("Your net pay this week is: %.2f\n", netPay);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using scanf("%d ") with a space after the %d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032984/using-scanfd-with-a-space-after-the-d)

Comment: This isn't Python. You need curly braces (`{` and `}`) around your `if` statements.

Comment: I would also recommend refactoring your code a bit; perhaps just calculate the `grossPay` et al. variables in if statements, then have only 3 `printf` calls at the end of your function.

Comment: Your formatting is pretty bad, too. You should put spaces before and after most operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*` [but not when dereferencing pointers], `%`, and the `op=` equivalents).

Comment: I'd also add spaces after commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you have `\n` at the end of your call to `scanf`---this requires it to read whitespace until the block of whitespace ends (i.e. a non-whitespace character). Just remove the `\n`.

As an additional note, you're missing curly brackets (`{`, `}`) around the code for your if statements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line:

```
scanf("%f\n",&hrs);
```

Instead, it should be:

```
scanf("%f",&hrs);
```

Fixed code, after also adding missing curly braces:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float hrs=0;
    float grossPay,taxes,netPay;
    float bpr=12.00;
    printf("The number of hours worked in a week: ");
    scanf("%f",&hrs);
    if (hrs<=40) {
        grossPay=(hrs*bpr);
        printf("Gross Pay:%f\n",grossPay);
        if (grossPay<=300) {
            taxes=0.15*grossPay;
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
        if (grossPay>300 && grossPay<=450) {
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*(grossPay-300);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
        if (grossPay>450) {
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*150+0.25*(grossPay-450);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
    }
    if (hrs>40) {
        grossPay=40*bpr+18.00*(hrs-40);
        printf("Gross Pay:%f\n",grossPay);
        if (grossPay<=300) {
            taxes=0.15*grossPay;
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
        if (grossPay>300 && grossPay<=450) {
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*(grossPay-300);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
        if (grossPay>450) {
            taxes=0.15*300+0.20*150+0.25*(grossPay-450);
            netPay=grossPay-taxes;
            printf("Total taxes:%f\n",taxes);
            printf("Net Pay:%f\n",netPay);
        }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not fully fixed code.

Comment: I' sorry, I'm used to working with python nowadays so I actually missed the problem with the braces.