# Can't figure out what happen with scanf("%[^\n]\n", input) in C language

Tags: c, scanf

```
char str[20];
scanf("%[^\n]\n", str);
printf(">>>>%s\n", str);
```

This is my understanding: 
the first part "[^\n]" means accepting any character except '\n' in order to obtain some character, like the space, from function scanf and store it in str.
The second \n is for match the \n which ends the scanf, otherwise the \n will release in input stream and left to next input action.

But when I run it, the result confused me.

```
xhkjdeiMac:c xhkj$ ./hello
aaaaaaa
ccc
>>>>aaaaaaa
```

As you can see, I first enter aaaaaaa and hit the enter key, I think it store the aaaaaa into str and already match the \n. But I have to enter something else, like ccc, then I can go to next step and print the str out on the console.

So why did it happen? why should I have to enter something else and hit the enter key again to finish the scanf?

Comment: Well I guess it still have to encounter that new line in [^\n] it just wont be saved. So if you would delete the last \n it should work.

Comment: Get rid of `'\n'` at the end. It is *whitespace*. `man 3 scanf` quoting `"A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input."` So `'\n'` at the end never matches anything -- it just tells `scanf` to ignore all whitespace (including none) at the end. You can fix your *format string* as `scanf(" %[^\n]", str);` (now note the `' '` **before** the opening `%`)

Comment: @Eraklon but it will left the \n in the input stream and lead to some problems if there is another scanf after that;   You can try it: 
char str[20];
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
printf(">>>>%s\n", str);
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
printf(">>>>%s\n", str);
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
printf(">>>>%s\n", str);

result:
xhkjdeiMac:c xhkj$ ./hello
a
>>>>a
>>>>a
>>>>a


You can see for first scanf, I entered a and hit enter key, it printed out, but I never get the chance to enter anything for the second scanf, it just printed 3 times in a row, it result from the \n left over at the first time.

Comment: Yes it will leave the `'\n'` after the final input and that can be a problem for your next input. That is why you are encouraged to use `fgets (str, sizeof str, stdin)` to read *line-oriented* input and then trim the included `'\n'` from the end of `str` with `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` New C programmers are plagued by the pitfalls of `scanf`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just watched a book which wrote in this way, and I thought I understand what that means, but when I run it, it's really plagued me

Comment: The issue with the `'\n'` at the end (it being whitespace), it causes `scanf` to ignore the `'\n'` that is generated by pressing **[Enter]**, so your string isn't printed until you enter more text (which is non-whitespace). The `'\n'` at the end causes the exact problem you describe. Use `if (scanf(" %[^\n]", str) == 1) printf (">>>>%s\n", str);`  (you cannot use any input function correctly without ***checking the return***)

Comment: How about `scanf("[^\n]%*c", str);`? That should read up to before the newline and read and discard the next character, which should be the newline. (The `*` in `%*c` suppresses assignment, so there is no corresponding pointer variable in the function arguments.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using scanf("%d ") with a space after the %d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032984/using-scanfd-with-a-space-after-the-d)

Comment: @IanAbbott `scanf("[^\n]%*c", str);` fails to achieve needed result when the first character is a `'\n'` or non-`'\n'` longer than 19 for OP.

Comment: @chux (Sorry for my typo earlier - missing a `%` in `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);`). That's true, but OP's `scanf("%[^\n]\n", str);` also fails when the first character is a `'\n'`, so it isn't any worse. Both versions have undefined behavior for a sequence of more than 19 non-`'\n'` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[20];
scanf("%[^\n]\n", str);
```

> OP: the first part `"[^\n]"` means accepting any character except '\n' in order to obtain some character, .... and store it in `str`.

Not quite.

If the first character read is a `'\n'`, scanning stops.  Nothing saved in `str`, no *null character* is appended, `'\n'` remains in `stdin` and function returns 0 or EOF ( I forget, but it is not 1)

Else non-`'\n'` characters are read and saved until a  `'\n'` is read.  That `'\n'` is put back into `stdin`, a *null character* is appended to `str`.  Scanning continues with format `"\n"`.  If 20 or more characters were read, the result in *undefined behavior*.

---

**Main problem**

> OP: The second \n is for match the \n which ends the scanf, otherwise the \n will release in input stream and left to next input action.

No.  Format `"\n"` matches any number of white-space, not just 1 `'\n'`.  `scanf()` consumes white-spaces like `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'`, ..., until a non-white-space character is read.  That non-white-space character is then put back into `stdin`.

> OP: why should I have to enter something else and hit the enter key again to finish the scanf?

The program is waiting was a non-white-space character before it returns.  Since `stdin` is typically *line* buffered, that non-white-space character is not given to `scanf()` until it has a following `'\n'`.

---

`scanf("%[^\n]\n", str);` is problematic.  Use `fgets()`.  Check return values.

```
char str[20];
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
  str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential trailing \n if desired
  printf(">>>>%s\n", str);
}
```

---

If one, *sigh*, must use `scanf()`, consider:

```
*str = 0;              // Handle case when first letter is \n
scanf("%19[^\n]", str);// Consume up to 19 characters
scanf("%*1[\n]");      // Consume 1 \n if present-independent of success of previous
```