# Type cast to a (double*)?

Tags: c

I'm trying to allocate memory through a function and store the proper data type in that memory, but my int didn't work without (*int), how do I apply that as a double? (*double) is not working

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int newInt ();
    double newDouble ();

    int main() {

        int userChoice;
        int userValue;
        int *intPtr;
        double *doublePtr;


printf("Please choose which type of value you'd like to store (1-4).");
puts("\n 1.) Int \n 2.) Double \n");
scanf("%d", &userChoice);

if (userChoice == 1) {

    intPtr = (int*)newInt();

    printf("You chose an Int, please enter an Int value\n");
    scanf("%d", *&intPtr); 

    printf("Memory value is %p \n", intPtr);
    printf("Stored value is %d", *intPtr);

} else if (userChoice == 2) {

    doublePtr = (double*)newDouble();

    printf("You chose a Double, please enter a Double value\n");
    scanf("%lf", *&doublePtr);

    printf("Memory value is %p \n", doublePtr);
    printf("Stored value is %lf", *doublePtr);
     return 0;
    }

    int newInt () {  
        malloc(sizeof(int));  
    }

    double newDouble () {
        malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
```

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Post actual code that we can compile debug and run.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Sonohi. As abelenky states, it is more helpful to include the code inline. Also, constructing a Minimal Reproducible Example is best: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that, updated!

Comment: probably you want `return malloc...`

Comment: And the `new` functions need to have pointer return types.

Comment: `*&` cancel each other out so you can drop that completely.

Comment: Re "*but my int didn't work without `(*int)`*", Wrong fix. The fix isn't to cast the result; the fix is to define the type of the value returned by the function correctly. It returns an `int*`(once you add the missing `return`), not a `int`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. It will identify lots of problems for you.

Comment: Re *"Turn on compiler warnings.*", Definitely. With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it.
Corrections in the comments.

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/7t8Nbo)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* newInt ();       // Changed the return type
double* newDouble (); // Changed the return type

int main() {
    int userChoice;
    // int userValue; Removing unused variable.
    int *intPtr;
    double *doublePtr;

    printf("Please choose which type of value you'd like to store (1-4).");
    puts("\n 1.) Int \n 2.) Double \n");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);

    if (userChoice == 1) {
        intPtr = newInt(); // Removed cast

        printf("You chose an Int, please enter an Int value\n");
        scanf("%d", intPtr); // Removed extra *&

        printf("Memory value is %p \n", intPtr);
        printf("Stored value is %d", *intPtr);

    } else if (userChoice == 2) {

        doublePtr = newDouble(); // Removed cast

        printf("You chose a Double, please enter a Double value\n");
        scanf("%lf", doublePtr); // Removed extra *&

        printf("Memory value is %p \n", doublePtr);
        printf("Stored value is %lf", *doublePtr);
    }
    return 0;
} // Added a missing bracket.

int* newInt () {                  // Changed the return type
    return malloc(sizeof(int));   // Added a return statement
}

double* newDouble () {             // Changed the return type
    return malloc(sizeof(double)); // Added a return statement
}
```

Comment: Note that the declaration and definitions should be `foo(void)` (no parameters), not `foo()` (unspecified number of parameters).

Comment: Just want to clarify so I'm understanding, are these functions returning a memory address?

Comment: @abelenky -- `// Added a space after %d`: it is almost always a mistake to use trailing whitespace characters in `scanf()` format strings. The input will block until some non-whitespace character is entered. [Read about the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032984/using-scanfd-with-a-space-after-the-d/43033218#43033218). And note that the `%d` directive automatically skips over leading whitespace characters anyway (as do all other `scanf()` directives except for `%c`, `%[]`, and `%n`) so it seems to serve no purpose here other than to interfere with user input.

Comment: Also: you need to cast pointers to `void *` when printing with `%p` to avoid undefined behavior.