# When I print my string it prints more than it's length

Tags: c

**My Code**

```
char str[100];
    scanf("%s\n",str);
    char str2[2];
    scanf("%c\n",&str2[0]);
    scanf("%c\n",&str2[1]);
    printf("%s",str2);
```

**Input**

```
abbcde
b
c
```

**Output**

```
bcabbcde
```

If str2 is of length two only why all this extra thing comes from,I have checked that input has been recorded correctly for both strings.

Comment: `str2` does not contain a string because it is not NUL terminated. You must not use `%s` which requires a string. Doing so results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: A string is a sequence of chars terminated by a `\0`. If you don't terminate the string, `printf` will go beyond your string and print whatever it finds in memory (in this case str). Increase str2 size to 3, set `str2[2] = 0` and all will be fine.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I think it will ask for one more character to give as stdin ?

Comment: Unrelated: trailing whitespace characters such as `\n` in `scanf()` format strings are almost always wrong, and [can cause havoc with user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033218/6879826). If you want to skip newline characters, add a space before the `%c` (i.e `" %c"`) following a previous call to `scanf()`.

Comment: @VishnuCS no it won't. What scanf expects doesn't depend on the size of the array you are writing in, but just on the format: %c _catches_ one char only.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `str2` is string it most end with `\0` and it length should be `3`.

look:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%s", str);
    char str2[3];
    scanf(" %c", &str2[0]);// add space
    scanf(" %c", &str2[1]);// add space
    str2[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str2);
}
```

also you shouldn't add this `\n` to your `scanf` because when you press enter it will automatically go  to next line ,but when you add `\n` to `scanf`(after data)it will wait for something except new line or white space to terminate.

Comment: Why is st2 of length 3, When null character is stored at str2[2] ?

Comment: @GauravKumar point about arrays is that ,they are indexed from 0, so when `str2` length is `3` .it means it has `3` elements  ,which are `a[0]` and `a[1]` and `a[2]`(3 element never include `a[3]`)

Answer (score 4):

The working code will be like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%s",str);
    char str2[3];
    scanf(" %c",&str2[0]); 
    scanf(" %c",&str2[1]);
    str[2]='\0';
    printf("%s",str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Fix 1:

> Unrelated: trailing whitespace characters such as \n in scanf() -- [@ex_nihilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752183/when-i-print-my-string-it-prints-more-than-its-length#comment107487459_60752183) already given a comment on this.

Fix 2:

> Space before %c removes any white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines)

Fix 3:

> If str2 is a string then the end character should be '\0' and we need to add this explicitly. For this we need to increase the size of str2 array to 3.

Comment: This is fine, _providing_ you don't want to be able to enter a space for either of the characters of `str2`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",str);` is bad like `gets(str);`  Use a width limit like `scanf("%99s",str);`

Answer (score 2):

> When I print my string it prints more than it's length

Code did not attempt to print a *string*.

`printf("%s",str2);` requires `str2` to be a *string*.  `str[2]` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  The result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

To print a character array like a *string*, even if it lacks a *null character*, use a *precision*.  Printing stops when the precision or a *null character* is reached.

```
// printf("%s",str2);
printf("%.*s", 2, str2);
```

Alternatively, make certain `str2[]` contains a *null character* and print as before.